# How to check if an intent can be handled on API 30+ (Android 10+, R)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

Below 30 API there were two methods I could use to check if intent can be handled by some app activity:

```
fun Intent.canBeHandled(packageManager: PackageManager): Boolean {
    return resolveActivity(packageManager) != null
}

fun PackageManager.isIntentCanBeHandled(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val infos = queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    return infos.isNotEmpty()
}
```

But when I test on Pixel 3 API 30 Emulator it doesn't work as expected, e.g. `queryIntentActivities()` returns usually 0 or 1 (e.g. 1 for send intent when it should have been 7, as it was with API 29-)

Basically `Intent.createChooser(intent, "")` works correctly and suggests 2 apps (for example) but ext funcs `Intent.canBeHandled()` & `PackageManager.isIntentCanBeHandled()` return false

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, this helped: `<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>`

Answer (score -2):

Intent needs to be created as a chooser - Please refer to last few lines of following example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String cstLogTag = "Implicit Intents";
private enum enuShare {shareCompat, shareSheet, intentResolver}
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    EditText editText;
    String strText, strButton;
    Uri uri;
    Intent chooser, intent;
    chooser = intent = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnWebsite:
            strButton = "btnWebsite";
            editText = findViewById(R.id.edtWebsite);
            strText = editText.getText().toString();
            uri = Uri.parse(strText);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            break;
        case R.id.btnLocation:
            strButton = "btnLocation";
            editText = findViewById(R.id.edtLocation);
            strText = editText.getText().toString();
            uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + strText);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            break;
        case R.id.btnShareText:
            strButton = "btnShareText";
            editText = findViewById(R.id.edtShareText);
            strText = editText.getText().toString();
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strText);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Testing");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(cstLogTag, "Button not recognised");
            return;
    }
    //intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) returns null so...
    chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose");
    if(chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null)
        Log.d(cstLogTag, "Unresolved activity for " + strButton);
    else
        startActivity(chooser);
}
```

}

Comment: you don't understand this problem, and it's already was solved, try to read comments below my question

Comment: and who said that it's necessarily to use chooser?